# Can the receiver of a saved wepbage I shared on chrome to Whatsapp access my mail

Tags: chrome

So I shared a webpage I wanted to print to a printshop via WhatsApp. When the operator opened the file, I could see my email and my name displayed on the print shops PC almost as if they have my email logged in. How's that possible since I never logged in there?

Comment: You shared a URL, a saved webpage (file) or a picture of the webpage? If it's the latter, of course they will see your private data.

Comment: I shared a saved webpage to their WhatsApp. Does that mean they can access my email or read it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I shared a saved webpage to their WhatsApp. Does that mean they can access my email or read it?

They can see your email address, that's it. You're safe.